# How to use attributes like FromBody in ASP.NET Core Minimal API with F#

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, c#-to-f#

With Minimal API, the handle looks like

```cs
app.MapGet("/", ([FromBody] Body body, [FromServices] Service service) => {...}));
```

in C#, but when using F#, the F# function is not acceptable here to convert to delegate automatically:

Case 1:

```ml
app.MapGet("/", fun ([<FromBody>] body: Body , [<FromServices>] service: Service )) -> ...))
```

it fails to compile.

Case 2:

```ml
app.MapGet("/", Func<Body, Service, IResult>(fun ([<FromBody>] body: Body , [<FromServices>] service: Service) -> ...))
```

it also fails

Case 3:

```ml
// Currying
app.MapGet("/", Func<Body, Service, IResult>(fun ([<FromBody>] body: Body) -> fun ([<FromServices>] service: Service) -> ...))
```

it makes the compiler happy, but fails at runtime.

I suspect when converting to `Func<>`, the attributes got removed

This is the error:

> Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromServices] or [FromBody] attribute?

So the question is, what's the right way to implement it?

Comment: Don't know minimal api's but your syntax of anonymous function in F# is wrong. Try to figure that first

Comment: My first sight is `[<FromBody>]` would be correct, but your `[FromServices]` could be wrong. So it must be `[<FromServices>]` in all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot define yet attributes in anonymous functions, but is possible to define them on top of methods or inside method signatures.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/attributes
- https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/984 (upvote this to add to anonymous methods / lambdas)

hope this answers your question

here is the "go to" HTTP web API libs

- [Giraffe](https://giraffe.wiki/) / [Saturn](https://saturnframework.org/)
- [Falco](https://www.falcoframework.com/) (probably best documented and integrated with middleware endpoints now)
- [Suave](https://suave.io/) (old but nice, works also in F# scripts)
- [Oxkpecker](https://medium.com/@lanayx/the-oxpecker-ef9df3dfb918) (experiment successor of Giraffe)
- [Fsharp.MinimalApi](https://github.com/lucasteles/FSharp.MinimalApi) (experiment)
- [FSharp.AspNetCore.WebAppBuilder](https://brianrourkeboll.github.io/FSharp.AspNetCore.WebAppBuilder/) (experiment)